# Derivatives of a B spline basis in R

Tags: r

I don't fully understand how to acquire the first and second derivative of a b spline basis for FDA in R. I have made attempts by changing the "order" of the series and using code that worked for a Fourier basis system.

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
gaitHip = gait[, , 1]
(gaittime <- as.numeric(dimnames(gaitHip)[[1]])*20)
gaitrange <- c(0,20)


# -----------  set up the harmonic acceleration operator  ----------

#harmaccelLfd <- vec2Lfd(c(0, (2*pi/20)^2, 0), rangeval=gaitrange)

Bsplineoperator <- int2Lfd(max(0, 2))

#  Set up basis for representing gaitHip data. 

Bsplinebasis = create.bspline.basis(gaitrange, nbasis=20, norder=4)


#  -------------------------------------------------------------------
#                 Choose level of smoothing using
#          the generalized cross-validation criterion
#  -------------------------------------------------------------------

#  set up range of smoothing parameters in log_10 units

gaitLoglam <- seq(-4,0,.25)
nglam   <- length(gaitLoglam)

gaitSmoothStats <- array(NA, dim=c(nglam, 3),
                         dimnames=list(gaitLoglam, c("log10.lambda", "df", "gcv") ) )
gaitSmoothStats[, 1] <- gaitLoglam

#  loop through smoothing parameters

for (ilam in 1:nglam) {
  gaitSmooth <- smooth.basisPar(gaittime, gaitHip, Bsplinebasis,
                                Lfdobj=Bsplineoperator, lambda=10^gaitLoglam[ilam])
  gaitSmoothStats[ilam, "df"]  <- gaitSmooth$df
  gaitSmoothStats[ilam, "gcv"] <- sum(gaitSmooth$gcv)
  # note: gcv is a matrix in this case
}

#  display and plot GCV criterion and degrees of freedom

op <- par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(gaitLoglam, gaitSmoothStats[, "gcv"],pch=19, type="b",
     xlab=expression("Log"[10]*lambda), ylab="GCV Criterion",
     main="Gait Smoothing", log="y")

gaitfd <- smooth.basisPar(gaittime, gaitHip,
                          Bsplinebasis,Lfdobj=Bsplineoperator, lambda=1e-1)$fd
names(gaitfd$fdnames) <- c("Normalized time", "Child", "Angle")
gaitfd$fdnames[[3]] <- c("Hip")

str(gaitfd)

Derivative1=deriv(gaitfd, Lfdobj=int2Lfd(1))
Derivative2=deriv(gaitfd, Lfdobj=int2Lfd(2))


CoefficientsHip=gaitfd[["coefs"]]
CoefficientsHip1=Derivative1[["coefs"]]
CoefficientsHip2=Derivative2[["coefs"]]
```

gaitHip <- structure(c(37, 36, 33, 29, 23, 18, 15, 12, 9, 6, 4, 6, 13, 22, 
31, 38, 43, 44, 40, 35, 47, 46, 42, 34, 27, 21, 16, 12, 4, -1, 
-2, 2, 12, 24, 34, 42, 47, 48, 45, 43, 46, 44, 39, 34, 33, 27, 
21, 15, 7, 1, -3, -1, 10, 22, 34, 43, 51, 53, 50, 49, 37, 36, 
27, 20, 15, 15, 10, 6, 3, 0, 3, 4, 10, 14, 23, 31, 33, 35, 34, 
32, 20, 18, 11, 8, 7, 5, 1, 0, -2, -4, -4, 1, 10, 18, 27, 36, 
34, 33, 32, 28, 57, 48, 44, 35, 31, 27, 21, 18, 14, 10, 8, 8, 
11, 21, 32, 40, 49, 55, 56, 55, 46, 38, 33, 25, 18, 15, 14, 10, 
8, 4, 0, 3, 9, 19, 31, 37, 46, 45, 46, 41, 46, 46, 43, 40, 36, 
30, 24, 17, 12, 7, 1, 3, 12, 24, 35, 44, 49, 49, 47, 43, 46, 
42, 37, 34, 31, 25, 19, 17, 13, 10, 5, 7, 13, 21, 29, 39, 47, 
51, 52, 47, 35, 34, 29, 28, 19, 15, 13, 6, 0, -1, 2, 11, 20, 
30, 39, 45, 48, 48, 43, 39, 38, 37, 33, 29, 26, 20, 14, 9, 3, 
-2, -1, 5, 15, 24, 36, 44, 47, 45, 42, 40, 35, 31, 29, 26, 22, 
19, 15, 11, 6, 3, 0, 4, 16, 27, 35, 41, 44, 45, 40, 39, 34, 31, 
27, 23, 19, 15, 13, 10, 6, 1, 0, 3, 8, 16, 27, 34, 40, 41, 39, 
36, 43, 41, 36, 31, 26, 20, 16, 13, 10, 8, 4, 12, 19, 27, 37, 
41, 44, 44, 41, 37, 43, 37, 35, 28, 26, 21, 20, 15, 13, 7, 3, 
8, 16, 25, 35, 43, 49, 50, 45, 46, 40, 41, 36, 32, 27, 20, 17, 
10, 5, -2, -4, -2, 7, 24, 38, 49, 57, 59, 54, 46, 51, 49, 45, 
39, 31, 23, 16, 9, 4, 0, -5, 1, 10, 21, 33, 44, 51, 55, 56, 51, 
52, 46, 41, 35, 31, 24, 18, 12, 6, 3, 2, 5, 12, 22, 32, 42, 46, 
48, 49, 46, 36, 33, 28, 22, 18, 13, 11, 7, 1, -2, -3, -3, 2, 
13, 22, 32, 39, 41, 38, 34, 35, 37, 33, 27, 22, 14, 9, 6, 4, 
-1, 1, 2, 11, 17, 34, 35, 40, 43, 43, 42, 46, 38, 30, 23, 17, 
13, 7, 3, 0, -3, -3, 1, 11, 20, 36, 48, 55, 57, 56, 50, 43, 41, 
37, 30, 24, 16, 12, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 16, 24, 33, 42, 48, 48, 48, 
46, 55, 51, 47, 41, 35, 30, 26, 23, 20, 11, 8, 10, 19, 35, 41, 
52, 57, 61, 63, 58, 39, 38, 31, 27, 21, 14, 9, 9, 6, 4, 2, 3, 
13, 30, 37, 47, 53, 53, 49, 44, 37, 34, 30, 27, 26, 19, 15, 10, 
4, 0, 0, 4, 12, 22, 31, 40, 43, 43, 38, 38, 36, 33, 28, 22, 18, 
13, 11, 7, 1, -2, -3, -3, 2, 13, 22, 32, 39, 41, 38, 34, 36, 
33, 30, 28, 21, 15, 8, 1, -5, -11, -12, -7, 4, 16, 26, 37, 44, 
47, 44, 37, 42, 40, 40, 34, 23, 15, 11, 7, 5, 6, 8, 12, 22, 33, 
43, 51, 57, 58, 54, 46, 38, 34, 30, 23, 17, 12, 8, 4, 1, 0, -4, 
-4, 1, 10, 22, 32, 38, 41, 41, 40, 46, 47, 44, 37, 29, 23, 19, 
14, 8, 3, -2, 1, 12, 26, 39, 48, 52, 48, 43, 42, 54, 48, 44, 
37, 30, 27, 21, 18, 15, 11, 12, 20, 30, 41, 50, 56, 61, 59, 57, 
58, 52, 44, 44, 33, 28, 27, 23, 24, 19, 15, 15, 16, 24, 32, 43, 
52, 58, 59, 57, 52, 32, 28, 26, 22, 19, 13, 8, 5, -1, -6, -5, 
0, 12, 22, 30, 36, 39, 36, 30, 29, 46, 41, 38, 31, 25, 20, 13, 
7, 1, -4, -3, -2, 8, 22, 34, 45, 53, 57, 55, 43, 46, 44, 40, 
35, 31, 25, 19, 15, 10, 5, 3, 6, 14, 27, 40, 48, 53, 53, 50, 
47, 48, 42, 42, 35, 30, 23, 19, 14, 9, 4, -1, 3, 9, 25, 37, 45, 
52, 53, 52, 46, 44, 41, 38, 32, 24, 18, 10, 6, 3, 0, -2, -1, 
6, 20, 36, 44, 49, 46, 38, 35, 55, 56, 51, 46, 41, 36, 30, 25, 
21, 15, 8, 5, 9, 19, 31, 43, 52, 56, 59, 59, 48, 50, 47, 42, 
37, 29, 22, 14, 8, 5, 8, 15, 24, 36, 51, 59, 63, 64, 61, 55), .Dim = c(20L, 
39L), .Dimnames = list(c("0.025", "0.075", "0.125", "0.175", 
"0.225", "0.275", "0.325", "0.375", "0.425", "0.475", "0.525", 
"0.575", "0.625", "0.675", "0.725", "0.775", "0.825", "0.875", 
"0.925", "0.975"), c("boy1", "boy2", "boy3", "boy4", "boy5", 
"boy6", "boy7", "boy8", "boy9", "boy10", "boy11", "boy12", "boy13", 
"boy14", "boy15", "boy16", "boy17", "boy18", "boy19", "boy20", 
"boy21", "boy22", "boy23", "boy24", "boy25", "boy26", "boy27", 
"boy28", "boy29", "boy30", "boy31", "boy32", "boy33", "boy34", 
"boy35", "boy36", "boy37", "boy38", "boy39")))

Comment: please provide the code you have tried and some sample data.

Comment: Did you realize that your matrix was all character?

Comment: Have edited it there. The data set is large so r will be needed to view it

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean? 42

Comment: Look at `str(gaitHip)`. It's a character matrix.